# Writing and Reading numpy objects an plain text

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

In Python, I would like to store numpy arrays, matrices and possibly later other objects in plain text format.

My idea was to use ConfigParser and define parser `array2string`, `matrix2string`, `string2array` and `string2matrix` (there is `numpy.array2string` and `matrix2string` could be implemented based on that, but I couldn't find functions for the reverse). Then writing looks like:

```
config.set('calibration', 'center', array2string(center))
config.set('calibration', 'trans_matrix', matrix2string(trans_matrix))
```

and reading like:

```
center = string2array(config.get('calibration', 'center'))
trans_matrix = string2matrix(config.get('calibration', 'trans_matrix'))
```

What is the best way to write and read the numpy objects?

Comment: In Python 3.4, Numpy 1.9, I am able to find `array2string`, but I cannot find `string2array`, `matrix2string` and `string2matrix`. From which package are these functions?

Comment: There are loads of methods to save arrays / matrices as strings in numpy. Start with [array_repr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_repr.html), [numpy.savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)

Comment: `array2string`, `matrix2string`, `string2array` and `string2matrix` are placeholders for the functions to be implemented. `numpy.savetxt` and `numpy.loadtxt` write to files and not strings and can't be used to write multiple arrays to a file. I couldn't find reverse functions for `numpy.array2string` and the like.

Comment: @magmabyte You could just use `savetxt` to save an array into a temporary file, read it as a string and remove the file after. Seriously, numpy provides a lot of useful methods. Have you tried them? Also there is `pickle` in standard Python library.

Comment: Writing to file and reading it in back as string to save it to another file for saving and vice versa for reading doesn't sound like an elegant solution. I am using `pickle` right now but it does not save the objects in plain text. I thought that there maybe is an elegant solution to it (especially one that writes and reads from strings and therefore allows me to use ConfigParser). I guess I'll use `numpy.array2string` for writing arrays and matrices and write the string2 parsers myself.

Answer (score 0):

Answer in this post gives a nice function which works well:

[how to read numpy 2D array from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612235/how-to-read-numpy-2d-array-from-string)

```
import configparser
import re
import ast
import numpy as np


def str2array(s):
    # Remove space after [
    s=re.sub('\[ +', '[', s.strip())
    # Replace commas and spaces
    s=re.sub('[,\s]+', ', ', s)
    return np.array(ast.literal_eval(s))


config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")
var_a = config.get("myvars", "var_a")
var_b = config.get("myvars", "var_b")
var_c = config.get("myvars", "var_c")


var_d=config.get("myvars", "var_d")

var_e=config.get("myvars", "var_e")

q=str2array(var_d)
r=str2array(var_e)
```

Where the config.ini file is:

```
# Variable tests
#
#

[myvars]
var_a='home'
var_b='car'
var_c=15.5
var_d=[2.1 3.4 4.6]
var_e=[[  1.1   2.2  2.233]
 [  1.00000000e+02   1.17809494e+03   4.9410e+02]
 [  2.00000000e+04   1.20e+01   1.2323e+04]]
```