# How to read NumPy 2D array from string?

Tags: python, numpy

How can I read a Numpy array from a string? Take a string like:

```
"[[ 0.5544  0.4456], [ 0.8811  0.1189]]"
```

and convert it to an array:

```
a = from_string("[[ 0.5544  0.4456], [ 0.8811  0.1189]]")
```

where `a` becomes the object: `np.array([[0.5544, 0.4456], [0.8811, 0.1189]])`.

I'm looking for a very simple interface. A way to convert 2D arrays (of floats) to a string and then a way to read them back to reconstruct the array:

`arr_to_string(array([[0.5544, 0.4456], [0.8811, 0.1189]]))` should return `"[[ 0.5544  0.4456], [ 0.8811  0.1189]]"`.

`string_to_arr("[[ 0.5544  0.4456], [ 0.8811  0.1189]]")` should return the object `array([[0.5544, 0.4456], [0.8811, 0.1189]])`.

Ideally `arr_to_string` would have a precision parameter that controlled the precision of floating points converted to strings, so that you wouldn't get entries like `0.4444444999999999999999999`.

There's nothing I can find in the NumPy docs that does this both ways. `np.save` lets you make a string but then there's no way to load it back in (`np.load` only works for files).

Comment: `json.loads` and `json.dumps` might be of use

Comment: I take that back, I didn't see the missing commas in the arrays...

Comment: i'm basically looking for the inverse of ``np.array_str`` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.array_str.html) but i can't find it

Comment: Is it possible for you to save the shape and just save the flattened array? Because if you can do that, you can easily use the existing methods. Just reshape it when you are ready to reconstitute. Also, are you sending the array to string in order to serialize? Does it have to be human readable?

Comment: Have you tried `pickle`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The challenge is to save not only the data buffer, but also the shape and dtype.  `np.fromstring` reads the data buffer, but as a 1d array; you have to get the dtype and shape from else where.

```
In [184]: a=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

In [185]: np.fromstring(a.tostring(),int)
Out[185]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])

In [186]: np.fromstring(a.tostring(),a.dtype).reshape(a.shape)
Out[186]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

A time honored mechanism to save Python objects is `pickle`, and `numpy` is pickle compliant:

```
In [169]: import pickle

In [170]: a=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

In [171]: s=pickle.dumps(a*2)

In [172]: s
Out[172]: "cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\np0\n(cnumpy\nndarray\np1\n(I0\ntp2\nS'b'\np3\ntp4\nRp5\n(I1\n(I3\nI4\ntp6\ncnumpy\ndtype\np7\n(S'i4'\np8\nI0\nI1\ntp9\nRp10\n(I3\nS'<'\np11\nNNNI-1\nI-1\nI0\ntp12\nbI00\nS'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x02\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x06\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x08\\x00\\x00\\x00\\n\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x0c\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x0e\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x10\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x12\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x14\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x16\\x00\\x00\\x00'\np13\ntp14\nb."

In [173]: pickle.loads(s)
Out[173]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  4,  6],
       [ 8, 10, 12, 14],
       [16, 18, 20, 22]])
```

There's a numpy function that can read the pickle string:

```
In [181]: np.loads(s)
Out[181]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  4,  6],
       [ 8, 10, 12, 14],
       [16, 18, 20, 22]])
```

You mentioned `np.save` to a string, but that you can't use `np.load`.  A way around that is to step further into the code, and use `np.lib.npyio.format`.

```
In [174]: import StringIO

In [175]: S=StringIO.StringIO()  # a file like string buffer

In [176]: np.lib.npyio.format.write_array(S,a*3.3)

In [177]: S.seek(0)   # rewind the string

In [178]: np.lib.npyio.format.read_array(S)
Out[178]: 
array([[  0. ,   3.3,   6.6,   9.9],
       [ 13.2,  16.5,  19.8,  23.1],
       [ 26.4,  29.7,  33. ,  36.3]])
```

The `save` string has a header with `dtype` and `shape` info:

```
In [179]: S.seek(0)

In [180]: S.readlines()
Out[180]: 
["\x93NUMPY\x01\x00F\x00{'descr': '<f8', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (3, 4), }          \n",
 '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00ffffff\n',
 '@ffffff\x1a@\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc#@ffffff*@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x800@\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc3@\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\x197@ffffff:@33333\xb3=@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80@@fffff&B@']
```

If you want a human readable string, you might try `json`.

```
In [196]: import json

In [197]: js=json.dumps(a.tolist())

In [198]: js
Out[198]: '[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]'

In [199]: np.array(json.loads(js))
Out[199]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Going to/from the list representation of the array is the most obvious use of `json`.  Someone may have written a more elaborate `json` representation of arrays.

You could also go the `csv` format route - there have been lots of questions about reading/writing csv arrays.

---

```
'[[ 0.5544  0.4456], [ 0.8811  0.1189]]'
```

is a poor string representation for this purpose.  It does look a lot like the `str()` of an array, but with `,` instead of `\n`.  But there isn't a clean way of parsing the nested `[]`, and the missing delimiter is a pain.  If it consistently uses `,` then `json` can convert it to list.

`np.matrix` accepts a MATLAB like string:

```
In [207]: np.matrix(' 0.5544,  0.4456;0.8811,  0.1189')
Out[207]: 
matrix([[ 0.5544,  0.4456],
        [ 0.8811,  0.1189]])

In [208]: str(np.matrix(' 0.5544,  0.4456;0.8811,  0.1189'))
Out[208]: '[[ 0.5544  0.4456]\n [ 0.8811  0.1189]]'
```

Comment: What a sophisticated and complete answer! Pickle is the best choice here.  I also needed to transfer quite large 2dim float arrays via AMQP and pickle did the job (even without json). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure there's an easy way to do this if you don't have commas between the numbers in your inner lists, but if you do, then you can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
import numpy as np
s = '[[ 0.5544,  0.4456], [ 0.8811,  0.1189]]'
np.array(ast.literal_eval(s))

array([[ 0.5544,  0.4456],
       [ 0.8811,  0.1189]])
```

EDIT: I haven't tested it very much, but you could use `re` to insert commas where you need them:

```
import re
s1 = '[[ 0.5544  0.4456], [ 0.8811 -0.1189]]'
# Replace spaces between numbers with commas:
s2 = re.sub('(\d) +(-|\d)', r'\1,\2', s1)
s2
'[[ 0.5544,0.4456], [ 0.8811,-0.1189]]'
```

and then hand on to `ast.literal_eval`:

```
np.array(ast.literal_eval(s2))
array([[ 0.5544,  0.4456],
       [ 0.8811, -0.1189]])
```

(you need to be careful to match spaces between digits but also spaces between a digit an a minus sign).

Comment: i don't have commas between the numbers, only spaces

Comment: @mvd You might try my edit, but I haven't tested it thoroughly.

Answer (score 10):

Forward to string:

```
import numpy as np
def array2str(arr, precision=None):
    s=np.array_str(arr, precision=precision)
    return s.replace('\n', ',')
```

Backward to array:

```
import re
import ast
import numpy as np
def str2array(s):
    # Remove space after [
    s=re.sub('\[ +', '[', s.strip())
    # Replace commas and spaces
    s=re.sub('[,\s]+', ', ', s)
    return np.array(ast.literal_eval(s))
```

If you use `repr()` to convert array to string, the conversion will be trivial.

Comment: This answer works nicely, as it can be used with configparser; which means comments can be the in a text file.   See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691797/writing-and-reading-numpy-objects-an-plain-text/61332772#61332772

Comment: The `\s` in `[,\s]+` in `strarray` not only replaces spaces, but also replaces whitespace as well -- so if your array is `[1 2]\n[3 4]`, then it works for such cases as well.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I found following command helpful for dumping:

```
string = str(array.tolist())
```

And for reloading:

```
array = np.array( eval(string) )
```

This should work for any dimensionality of numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

numpy.fromstring() allows you to easily create 1D arrays from a string. Here's a simple function to create a 2D numpy array from a string:

```
import numpy as np

def str2np(strArray):

    lItems = []
    width = None
    for line in strArray.split("\n"):
        lParts = line.split()
        n = len(lParts)
        if n==0:
            continue
        if width is None:
            width = n
        else:
            assert n == width, "invalid array spec"
        lItems.append([float(str) for str in lParts])
    return np.array(lItems)
```

Usage:

```
X = str2np("""
    -2  2
    -1  3
     0  1
     1  1
     2 -1
     """)
print(f"X = {X}")
```

Output:

```
X = [[-2.  2.]
 [-1.  3.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]
 [ 2. -1.]]
```