# Python - read_csv

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I am storing a 3D numpy array in a pandas DataFrame "df" cell :

```
arr =np.array([[[1,2],[1,3]],[[1,2],[2, 3]]])

df.at[0,'column_A'] = arr #first row, col A
```

I save the csv file with :

```
df.to_csv("dataframe", sep='\t')
```

I then load it with:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv("dataframe", sep='\t')
```

However, the array loaded is now a string :
`'[[[1 2]\n  [1 3]]\n\n [[1 2]\n  [2 3]]]'`

How can I get back the original array ?
Is there something wrong in the way I am saving the csv ?
Thanks !

Comment: numpy has a built-in way of storing numeric arrays (`np.save`). This is great if you do not want to access the data with an editor or Excel. I usually don't use pandas, but I believe it will (by default) read the csv content as string. If you don't want that, there is the `converter` argument, oder you convert manually.

Comment: text files (such as csv) cannot understand numpy arrays, so you have to change that column back to array after you read it as string:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612235/how-to-read-numpy-2d-array-from-string