# How to convert 3D string to numpy array which is originated after saving 3D image in CSV

Tags: python, numpy

I have a CSV file, which has one column with image data. Before saving to CSV each image was a 3D numpy array. So each cell of this column was a 3D array. After saving to CSV and reading using pandas they converted to string. Now I want to recreate an array from them. Below you can find a sample of string which I want to convert to 3D numpy array.

```
import numpy as np

my_string_array = str(np.random.randint(0, high=255, size=(51, 52, 3)))
```

I tried the staff described here [how to read numpy 2D array from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612235/how-to-read-numpy-2d-array-from-string), but seems that I need to have something different, since I have 3D array.

I know that if the arrays were converted to `list` before saving to CSV, then

```
import ast
my_array = np.array(ast.literal_eval(my_string_array))
```

would work, but unfortunately this is not the case. After running this I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/lyp-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3319, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-25-3e5a6dae7682>", line 2, in <module>
    my_array = np.array(ast.literal_eval(my_string_array))

  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 46, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')

  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

  File "<unknown>", line 1
    [[[205  60 145]
             ^  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: If your string really has `...` in it, you won't be able to recover the data.

Comment: The linked question fully answers yours. It is not limited to 2D

Comment: @MadPhysicist can you please specify which one ? It does not contain `...` you will not see them if you use `print( my_string_array)` .

Comment: `print(str(np.random.randint(0, high=255, size=(51, 52, 3))))` results in seven ellipses

Comment: @MadPhysicist yep you are right, it contains `...` when print, but what is the issue with that?

Comment: Most of your data is in the ellipsis. You can't get it back.

Comment: The `...` is likely the problem, BUT when asking a question like this, you really should show the error.  Don't just say "it didn't work"; show what you tried and what the error message was.  Why did you think the 3d was the issue?  Was there something in the error that suggested that?

Comment: @hpaulj I mentioned that tried the answers mentioned in the similar question and got different errors, since there are different answers. I do not understand your comment clearly. What exactly do you want to see in the question ? The question is about the method which could solve the problem, rather than to solve any specific error. So the question is specify, what is the algorithm to de-parse 3D str array to array.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error that you added:

```
ast.literal_eval(my_string_array)
....
[[[205  60 145]
         ^  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`literal_eval` works on a limited subset of Python syntax.  For example it will work on a valid list input, e.g. `"[[205, 60, 145]]"`.  But the string in the error message does not match that; it's missing the commas.  The `str(an_array)` omits the commas.  `str(an_array.tolist())` does not.

Most of the answers that deal with loading `csv` files like this stress that you will need to replace the spaces (or blank delimiters) with commas.

So in this case the error has nothing to do with the array being 3d.

Let me illustrate:

make 3d array:

```
In [720]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)                                                     

In [722]: arr                                                                                    
Out[722]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

It's `str` representation, which is probably what `pandas` writes to the csv:

```
In [723]: str(arr)                                                                               
Out[723]: '[[[ 0  1  2  3]\n  [ 4  5  6  7]\n  [ 8  9 10 11]]\n\n [[12 13 14 15]\n  [16 17 18 19]\n  [20 21 22 23]]]'
```

Compare that with what a list str looks like:

```
In [724]: arr.tolist()                                                                           
Out[724]: 
[[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]],
 [[12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23]]]
In [725]: str(arr.tolist())                                                                      
Out[725]: '[[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]], [[12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23]]]'
```

`literal_eval` has no problem with this triple nested list string:

```
In [726]: ast.literal_eval(_)                                                                    
Out[726]: 
[[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]],
 [[12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23]]]
```

`literal_eval` applied to the array string produces your error:

```
In [727]: ast.literal_eval(Out[721])                                                             
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3319, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-727-700e3f960e29>", line 1, in <module>
    ast.literal_eval(Out[721])

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 48, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

  File "<unknown>", line 1
    [[[ 0  1  2  3]
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I might be able to fix that with a couple of string substitutions, effectively converting `Out[721]` to `Out[725]`.

@Mad pointed out that if the array is large enough (over 1000 elements) `str` will produce a condensed version, replacing a lot of the values with '...'.  You can verify that yourself.  If that is the case, no amount of string editing will fix the problem.  That string is useless.

In [how to read numpy 2D array from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612235/how-to-read-numpy-2d-array-from-string), my answer has limited values since you already have string.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44323021/901925 is better. I've also SO questions that deal specifically with the strings that appear in `pandas` csv.   In any case you need to pay attention to the details of the string, especially delimiters and special characters.