# Trouble converting matrix stored as string in excel to numpy array when using pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, string-conversion

I am having a hard time reading in an excel file with `pandas DataFrame` and converting a stored matrix to a `numpy array`. I think part of the issue is that the matrix is improperly stored. I have no control over the spreadsheet however, this is how it was sent to me.

For instance this is the string stored in a cell

```
[[[ 0.        0.        0.107851]
  [ 0.        0.       -0.862809]]]
```

I read in the row with `DataFrame`, and save each cell to a variable. I then try to convert this particular variable to a `np.array` since those number represent two sets of x, y, z coordinates.

I have tried `np.fromstring` and `np.asarray` to no avail. It will convert the string to a numpy array but it will be a terrible mess with the brackets still inside as characters. I have tried using np.squeeze to get rid of the brackets but it says dimension is not 1.

if I use `np.asarray(item._coord, dtype=float)` then it fails saying it cannot convert the string to float.

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[[[ 0.        0.        0.107851]   [ 0.        0.       -0.862809]]]'`

There is a '\n' that shows up in the middle of it, between the two lists. I use `df = df.replace(r'\n', ' ',regex=True)' to clean out the`\n`'s prior to data conversion attempts.

I am stuck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use custom function for convert to `numpy array` after [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
a= np.array([[[ 0.,        0.,        0.107851],
              [ 0.,        0.,       -0.862809]]])
print (a)
[[[ 0.        0.        0.107851]
  [ 0.        0.       -0.862809]]]

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[a,a,a]})
print (df)
                                               col
0  [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.107851], [0.0, 0.0, -0.862809]]]
1  [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.107851], [0.0, 0.0, -0.862809]]]
2  [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.107851], [0.0, 0.0, -0.862809]]]

df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False)
```

---

```
import re
import ast
import numpy as np

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/44323021
def str2array(s):
    # Remove space after [
    s=re.sub('\[ +', '[', s.strip())
    # Replace commas and spaces
    s=re.sub('[,\s]+', ', ', s)
    return np.array(ast.literal_eval(s))

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

df['col'] = df['col'].apply(str2array)
print (df)
                                               col
0  [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.107851], [0.0, 0.0, -0.862809]]]
1  [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.107851], [0.0, 0.0, -0.862809]]]
2  [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.107851], [0.0, 0.0, -0.862809]]]
```

Comment: Thanks, just trying to get this working. In making a MWE I had to leave out some things. I think this is going to work though. It will be a few more minutes before my incompetent self gets to a conclusion.

Comment: Awwwww Yeahhhhh, it runs like a well oiled machine!

Comment: Final comment - I used the very last option `df['col'] = df['col'].apply(str2array)`

Comment: @CharlieCrown - Mea culpa, I later realised it is not csv, but excel, so `converter` cannot be used.